# Unable to create specified window panes

Tags: shell, tmux

I am trying to create a tmux script that does thee following

- **1st parameter** takes "start" or "stop"
- **2nd parameter** takes "session-name"
- **3rd parameter** takes "two" or "three" or none, for creating window panes
- **4th parameter** takes "session-path"

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

SESSION=$2
if [ $1="start" ] && [ $3="two" ]; then
  echo "Starting a session with $3 window pane"
  tmux new -session -d -s $SESSION
  tmux new-window -t $SESSION:2 -n $3
  tmux select-window -t $SESSION:2
  tmux split-window -h
  tmux attach -t $SESSION
elif [ $1="start" ] && [ $3="three" ]; then
  echo "Starting a session with $3 window pane"
  tmux new -session -d -s $SESSION
  tmux new-window -t $SESSION:3 -n $3
  tmux select-window -t $SESSION:3
  tmux split-window -h
  tmux split-window -h
  tmux attach -t $SESSION
else
  echo "Starting a session with no window pane"
  tmux new -session -d -s $SESSION
  tmux new-window -t $SESSION:3 -n $3
  tmux select-window -t $SESSION:3
  tmux attach -t $SESSION
fi
```

I am able to create a tmux session with 2 window panes but unable to create 3 window panes.Is the elif executed when I pass?

```
script.sh start three three
```

For the session path fourth parameter, Is this the right syntax?

```
tmux send-keys $4 C-m
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixes creating 2 or 3 window panes:

```
#!/bin/bash

SESSION=$2

case $1 in
  start)
    echo "starting session"
    if [ $3 == "two" ]; then
      echo "Creating 2 window pane"
      tmux new -session -d -s $SESSION
      tmux new-window -t $SESSION:2 -n 'two'
      tmux select-window -t $SESSION:2
      tmux split-window -h
      tmux attach -t $SESSION
    elif [ $3 == "three" ]; then
      echo "Creating 3 window pane"
      tmux new -session -d -s $SESSION
      tmux new-window -t $SESSION:3 -n 'three'
      tmux select-window -t $SESSION:3
      tmux split-window -h
      tmux split-window -h
      tmux attach -t $SESSION
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "stop session"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Wooot!"
    ;;
esac
```

For the fourth-parameter, you can try:

```
tmux send-keys "cd ${4}" Enter
```